# jquery storing properties in elements?

Tags: jquery, theory

I have a select element.

This element is looped over using jquery,

any options that are `:selected` are added to one list(lista)

any options that are `:not(':selected')` are added to another (listb)

these lists follow the structure of

```
<div id="lista">
  <div>1st selected option text <div class="button"></div></div>
  <div>2nd selected option text <div class="button"></div></div>
</div>

<div id="listb">
  <div>1st non selected option text <div class="button"></div></div>
  <div>2nd non selected option text <div class="button"></div></div>
</div>
```

Now my question is:
I would like to upon clicking the div with class `button` change it to either `selected` or not `selected` in the original select.

But I am not sure of the best place to store the `value` of the original `option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/). It is a mechanism for storing arbitrary data associated with a DOM element.

> **jQuery.data( element, key, value )**
>
> The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks

you can use the element shortcut:

```
$("#listb").data("key", "value");
```